# High rep users suggesting edits to authors

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I came upon a question where I wanted to make an edit, but I wasn't sure if it would change the original meaning of the question - as I did not know enough about the subject material to be sure.

I could wait for another user to come around and make the edit, but perhaps they wouldn't notice the problem that I wanted to edit. I could also suggest the edit in the comments, but it is such a minor nitpick of grammar that I seemed like a waste of a comment.

Of course, I can't just let a minor grammatical mistake go unnoticed.

So my suggestion is to allow an editor to mark an edit to instead be suggested *to the author* for approval, if the author believes it does not sufficiently alter the meaning of the question. It would pop up under their usual notification area to approve or reject a suggested edit.

This is different than the 5k/mod suggested edits version in that it would be from a user who could have edited the question, but still seeks the approval of the original poster.

Comment: I'd just post a comment.  If you're not sure whether it would change the meaning, then it's probably not just "a minor nitpick of grammar".  It could also give the original poster an opportunity to phrase the question more clearly than you might be able to (given greater knowledge of the subject matter).

Comment: [This is the question that prompted me to post here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51279/how-to-beat-sky-o-love-challenge-mission), the sentence "It was really difficult let the lovers meet" doesn't make sense, but how do you fix that? "It was really difficult _to_ let the lovers meet"? I don't know enough about what is going on in the game he is asking about to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minor grammatical errors aren't important enough to edit on their own.  If there are only minor grammatical errors and you don't know enough to intelligently edit it for content errors, leave it alone; someone else with more knowledge in the subject area AND the ability to edit will likely see and make the necessary corrections.  You CAN make whatever edits you think are necessary and if they do change the sense of the question the author is free to roll them back.  If you think it's a content issue but don't feel confident making the changes, a comment would be appropriate (and you can mention the grammar at the same time).

My suggestion is to relax and let the rest of the community do their job.  You don't have to clean up everything, just the corner of the world you feel comfortable working on.

Comment: ... to add to tvanfosson's point about leaving a comment; a comment to a users post **will** give them a notification, so it'll hold the same weight to your *suggested edit* idea.